# How to plot logistic regression with categorical variables as independent variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, data-science, logistic-regression

As dependent variables, I have a data frame with 0s and 1s (using certain product or not). As independent variables, I have a set of data frames with categorical variables (living in brick house, etc.). I plot logistic regression using ggplot:

```r
g <- ggplot(decision, aes(x=decision_point, y=use)) + geom_point(alpha=.1, size=2, col="red") +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", 
    method.args = list(family = "binomial"), 
    aes(x = as.numeric(decision_point)), 
    se = F)
```

What happens is that it plots a straight line. It seems the categorical variables are turned into numeric (as I wrote) and it just goes through it.

But if I don't use as.numeric, no line shows at all.

What can I do? The line should be a curve. So if independent variables were incremental numeric values, like 0-100, then plotting a curve would be easy. But they are categorical variables, like "Brick House" "Hut", "Others". Hence the problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Without seeing your data for an image of your graph, any advice is just a guess.

Comment: @Dave2e Thank you. The line is literally a straight line. The dependent variables and 0s and 1s. The independent variables are "Brick house," "Hut," and "Others."

Comment: @Dave2e If beyond this description there can be some other information regarding the data that you'd need, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe it is a straight line because there is no relationship between the dependent value and the output. Maybe the glm model in the geom_smooth function is incorrect. As I said before this is just a guess. It looks like you data is just 2 columns (decision_point & use), can you add a sample of your data to the question using the `dput` function?

Comment: @Dave2e Thank you. I've run glm(), and there is a definite relationship. The problem is that the line acts as if each categorical variable is 0, 1, 2, 3, because I converted them into numeric. And if I don't convert, there's no line at all. The same question has been raised in stackoverflow with no answers. So I'm curious if plotting logistic on categorical variables as independent variables is possible at all.

Comment: Agree with @Dave2e: This could be an easy or difficult question to solve, but without a minimal example set of data it's almost impossible.